# How can I get a timeout exception in WCF using TcpClient Class

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a certain issue which I'm facing. My contract implementation (besides other stuff) has something like this:

```cs
try
            {

                response = _socketRequest.SendRequest(request, emmiterHeader);
                trCode = response.TraceCodeInt;
                if (trCode == 0)
                    statusRequest = (int) TSRequestAttemptStatus.active;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException tex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                statusRequest = (int) TSRequestAttemptStatus.notActive;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                tsra = CreateTireaSincoRequestAttemptRow(DateTime.Now, statusRequest, emmiterHeader.HeaderId,
                                                         string.Empty,
                                                         string.Empty,
                                                         string.Empty,
                                                         previousContractNumber,
                                                         taxIdentificationCode,
                                                         policyHolderName,
                                                         policyHolderFirstName,
                                                         policyHolderLastName,
                                                         registrationNumberType.Substring(0, 1),
                                                         registrationNumber,
                                                         ((byte) ControlCodes.F),
                                                         DateTime.Now.AddDays(emmiterHeader.ValidityPeriod));
            }
```

Then in

_socketRequest.SendRequest(request, emmiterHeader);

Among other stuff is something like below:

```cs
using (var client = new TcpClient(header.SocketServerAddress,
                                      header.SocketServerPort == null ? 1 : (int)header.SocketServerPort))
                    {

                   Socket socket = client.Client;

                        // send data with timeout 10s
                        //socket.Send(arr);

                        Send(socket, arr, 0, arr.Length, 1000);

                        if (header.DebugMode)
                            _logger.LogInfo(InterfaceName, string.Format("Data Socket Send: {0} ", tempArr));
                        // receive data with timeout 10s
                        //Receive(client, arr);

                        len = Receive(socket, arrResponse, 0, arrResponse.Length, 5000, header.DebugMode, _logger);

                        if (socket.Connected)
                            socket.Close();

                        if (client.Connected)
                            client.Close();
                    }
```

The part under the using key word is never called because built in WCF Client is "hanging" on the TCPClient part, whcich in conclusion raises a SocketExeption error. I have set the timeouts in the web config to lets say 5 seconds. What I like to achieve is to throw not socket exception but the timeout exception. It looks like the SocketException is thrown but I can't make my wcf service throw a timeout exception. Is it possible to do that? I hope my questin is understandable what I want to do. If not I will try to explain as clearly as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TcpClient does not know or care what you talk to. It has no notion of WCF, web services or the `TimeoutException` that you want.

All it does it maintain a TCP connection.

Catch the `SocketException` and analyze the error code stored in it. There is a code for timeouts. Throw `TimeoutException` yourself.

---

And get rid of this superstitious dispose stuff:

```
                    if (socket.Connected)
                        socket.Close();

                    if (client.Connected)
                        client.Close();
```

Once is enough.

Comment: thank you for the answer I will try your solution but, how to do it? By error code you mean the property of the SocketExeption? If so is there any table refference what code is generated when there is a timeout?

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I've gooogled it and I think that under Socket exception I will do something like this:  if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                    throw new TimeoutException("TireaSinco service timeout"); is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok it works !! :) The last final question is. In this conditions (that is having this error code check used) in your opinion, do I need a configuration on WCF for timeouts?

Comment: Ok one other thing. I was testing with WCF Test clinet and it has it's own config file (at it looks like it has). There I've setup the time  after which I'm expecting timeout and it works also :) thanks for your help. Your solution is also needed to :)

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. You can configure any WCF timeout you want. I don't see any problem there.